# Unable to run command in function (shell script)

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, zshrc

I have this function in my `~/.zshrc`

```bash
async () {
    if ! [[ $# -gt 0 ]];then
        echo "Not enough arguments!"
    fi
    local busus="$IFS"
    export IFS=" "
    echo "$* &"
    command "$* &"
    export IFS="$busus"
}
```

and an alias

```bash
alias word='async "libreoffice --writer"'
```

The `echo "$* &"` line is used only for debugging.
When I run `word`, `libreoffice --writer &` is shown on the screen (no extra spaces or newlines), but nothing happens.
I also tried executing `command libreoffice --writer &` and it worked perfectly.
(My current shell is zsh)
What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the extra quotes after `command`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually (especially in bash), the problem is that people aren't using enough double-quotes; in this case, it's the opposite: you're using too many double-quotes. The basic problem is that the command name and each of the arguments to it must be a separate "word" (in shell syntax), but double-quoting something will (usually) make the shell treat it as all one word. Here's a quick demo:

```
% echo foo
foo
% "echo foo"
zsh: command not found: echo foo
```

Here, the double-quotes make the shell treat " foo" as part of the command name, rather than as a delimiter and an argument *after* the command name. Similarly, when you use `"$* &"`, the double-quotes tell the shell to treat the entire thing (including even the ampersand) as a single long word (and pass it as an argument to `command`). (BTW, the `command` isn't needed, but isn't causing any harm either.)

The standard way to do this is to use `"$@"` instead -- here the `$@` acts specially within double-quotes, making each argument into a separate word. In zsh, you could omit the double-quotes, but that can cause trouble in other shells so I recommend using them anyway.

Also, don't mess with `IFS`. You don't need to, and it opens a can of worms that's best left closed. And if there are no arguments, you should `return` immediately, rather than continuing and trying to run an empty command.

But there's another problem: in the alias, you double-quote `"libreoffice --writer"`, which is going to have pretty much the same effect again. So remove those double-quotes. But keep the single-quotes around the alias, so it'll be defined as a single alias.

So here's my proposed correction:

```
async () {
    if ! [[ $# -gt 0 ]];then
        echo "Not enough arguments!"
        return 1    # Do not continue if there's no command to run!
    fi
    echo "$* &"    # Here quoting is appropriate, so it's a single argument to echo
    "$@" &
}

alias word='async libreoffice --writer'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `"$@"` directly is more reliable:

```bash
async () { [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && "$@" & }

alias word='async libreoffice --writer'
```